# "FormatException was unhandled" deleting from database using linq-to-sql

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I've been reading around linq-to-sql CRUD operations, and from what I can tell, I'm going about this the correct way, but there is something wrong in the details.

my notes collection is not connected in to the data context in any way. It contains the items which need deleting and then inserting.

```
List<NoteItem> notes = ConvertJsonToModel(apiResponse);
```

and this works fine...

```
foreach (NoteItem note in notes)
{
    Db.NoteItems.InsertOnSubmit(note);
}
Db.SubmitChanges();
```

However, Db.NoteItems is already populated, so I need to update items which exist. Just to keep things simple for now, before I do the above insert, I'm trying to perform deletes on the existing items (I'll play with getting updates to work after I master deletes).

```
foreach (NoteItem note in notes)
{
    Db.NoteItems.Attach(note);
    Db.NoteItems.DeleteOnSubmit(note);
}
Db.SubmitChanges();
```

The error I get is:

**FormatException was unhandled**

which is odd, because I can insert the exact same note which gives an error, but I can't delete it.

NoteItem has 3 properties: string Id, DateTime ModifiedAt, string Text, as well as PropertyChanging and PropertyChanged events.

**Update**

I just discvoered the error does not occur on all records, so is data specific. Yet the same data works fine for an insert.

**Stacktrace**

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  Message=FormatException
  StackTrace:
       at System.Int32.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Data.Linq.DBConvert.ChangeType(Object value, Type type)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.BuildKeyValues(TrackedObject item)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DoResultSetDelete(TrackedObject item)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Delete(TrackedObject item)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
       at DrivenNotes.ViewModels.NotesViewModel.OnOnePageUpdated(Object sender, StreamCompleteEventArgs e)
       at DrivenNotes.ApiCommunication.ApiComms.OnGotStreamPage(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
       at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
       at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Comment: What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: I'm running on WP7 emulator, so not entirely sure how to get to the stack trace

Comment: Not running it in Visual Studio under the debugger?

Comment: Added the stacktrace. I'm so used to seeing the asp.net yellow screen of death that I forgot how to get it from within VS!

Comment: Also added an update: the error does not occur on all notes, it is data specific

Comment: Is `id` a string in the database too? It would seem it tries to convert a field to an int, and `id` is my best guess.

Comment: You got it. Feel free to add as an answer. It seems the API used to return only integers, so my Local Database was set up with type int. At some point I spotted the API was using hexadecimal Ids for some records and so I changed the model, but not the database. Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error stems from EF trying to convert a `string` to an `int` during `SubmitChanges()` and encountering a string it cannot convert.

Most likely there's a database/model mismatch on one of the columns, most likely `Id`.

Comment: Correct! Although NoteItem.Id is correctly a string, I had incorrectly made Id in the database an int. (My data was from an external source, and most of the Ids I had observed were integers, I now know that later data has hexadecimal Ids)